# Requesting Client Certificate Dynamically

Tags: certificate, x509, pki, client-certificates

Web Servers have settings by which you request client certificates - for eg. `SSLVerifyClient require` in Apache, a different setting in IIS etc. If this is set, then the browser throws up a dialog asking you to chose a certificate.

Is it possible to ask for a certificate dynamically? i.e. I am really not interested in 2 way SSL - however, I want to ask the user to register his certificate with my application which will be used in a different context. So I need to let the user chose one of the certs registered in his browser and access the cert in my application. How do I do this?

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out one way to do this - I have a upload link in my application - this points to a Virtual Directory which has `Client Side Authentication` required property. So when the user clicks on the link - it triggers a SSL Renegotiation. The browser throws a dialog which lets the user chose from the registered certs. Once he chosen the certificate, SSL renegotiation happens and the I can access the cert in the application. The SSL renegotiation ensures that the user has the private key corresponding to the Cert.

If there any problems with this method or if there is a better way to do this, I am most certainly interested in doing it.

Also, I am currently doing this in IIS - but I think something like this should be possible in most other webservers also.